# Enviar arquivo no Response via API Django

Tags: python, api, django, django-rest-framework, response

Tenho um backend em Django-Rest-Framework e estou precisando pegar um arquivo de uma pasta chamada **_media** por meio de uma coluna chamada **anexo** de uma Model, depois enviar no meu Response esse arquivo juntamente com outros dados.

*Meu settings:*

```
MEDIA_URL = '/_media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '.../backend/_media'
```

*Minha Model:*

```
from django.db import models

class SolicitacoesCompras(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    ...
    anexo = models.FileField(upload_to="compras/%Y/%m/%d", blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

*Meu Serializer:*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
...

class SolicitacoesComprasReponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = SolicitacoesCompras
        fields = (
            "id",
            "anexo",
            ...
        )
        depth = 1
```

*Minha View:*

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView, Response, Request, status
from .models import SolicitacoesCompras
...

class SolicitacoesComprasDetailView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request, id: int) -> Response:
        solicitacao = get_object_or_404(SolicitacoesCompras, id=id)
        serializer = SolicitacoesComprasReponseSerializer(solicitacao)

        return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

*Minha URL:*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "solicitacoes-compras/<int:id>/",
        views.SolicitacoesComprasDetailView.as_view(),
        name="solicitacoes-compras-id",
    ),
```

Como exemplo,

Tenho um arquivo nesse diretório:
`_media/compras/2023/06/06/124103.pdf`

E tenho um dado no meu banco de dados da tabela **SolicitacoesCompras** na coluna **anexo** com o valor:
`compras/2023/06/06/124103.pdf`

Ao acessar a rota **/api/solicitacoes-compras/5/** trás o seguinte json:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    ...
    "anexo": "/_media/compras/2023/06/06/124103.pdf",
    ...
}
```

Gostaria que o **anexo** do json fosse o arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

No seu serializer `SolicitacoesComprasReponseSerializer`. Seu código de exemplo:

```
from django.conf import settings

class SolicitacoesComprasReponseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    anexo_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_anexo_url(self, obj):
        if obj.anexo:
            return settings.MEDIA_URL + str(obj.anexo)

    class Meta:
        model = SolicitacoesCompras
        fields = (
            "id",
            "anexo",
            "anexo_url",
            ...
        )
        depth = 1
```

Em seguida, modifique o método get da sua view `SolicitacoesComprasDetailView`:

```
class SolicitacoesComprasDetailView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request, id: int) -> Response:
        solicitacao = get_object_or_404(SolicitacoesCompras, id=id)
        serializer = SolicitacoesComprasReponseSerializer(solicitacao)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

E ao acessar a rota `/api/solicitacoes-compras/5/`, você obterá este JSON:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    ...
    "anexo": "compras/2023/06/06/124103.pdf",
    "anexo_url": "/_media/compras/2023/06/06/124103.pdf",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a mudança que deveria ocorrer no método GET da minha view.